# Android: Using SQLiteOpenHelper. Should I use a ContentProvider?

Tags: android

I am developing an Android application.

So far I've created my own SQLiteOpenHelper as a singleton and a synchronized getInstance().

I am not sure if I should be also using a ContentProvider. I understand that Android uses it to match the Activity that should open my Intent, but should I be using it in my application?

What sort of direct advantages could I have if I use one? I am starting the application and I would love to use as much best practices as I can.

Can I add it later? I can't seem to fully understand the function of these ContentProviders.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only really need to bother with a ContentProvider if you intend to syndicate your content to an external application (for example, if you want your content to used as an email attachment, or you want a third party application to access your data). Otherwise if you'll just be using the data from within your application stick with a local SQLite instance.

Comment: Its always if I want external apps to access my data? If I want, for example, to create a report, and attach it to an email from my application, I still don't need one right?

Comment: If you are calling the installed email clients (Email, GMail) with an Intent and private data then you will need a ContentProvider. You may be able to get away with creating a world-readable file on the SD card and using that, but in general I've used a ContentProvider for sending email attachments.

Comment: Thats odd. I would think its easier to just put whatever I want as extras in the Intent. Well, I'll look into it when I have to. Right now, its enough for me to know that I wont have to change a lot of code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you're attaching a 4 MB file, you're not going to be putting that into the Intent. See http://www.kiwiluv.com/techblog/?p=1011 for a longer writeup.